# excluding id field in an inline formset when saving

Tags: python, django, inline-formset

I have two models, connected by a foreign key.  One is an inline formset.  For some reason, the formset ids are being identified as Primary Keys in the database, and every time the form is submitted, the table belonging to the formset is basically overwritten. When saving, how do I ignore the formset ids

models.py

```
class Student(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    email = models.EmailField()

class Courses(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student)
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    start_time = models.TimeField()
```

forms.py

```
class CoursesForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Courses
        exclude = ("student",)


class StudentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Student
       fields = "__all__"
```

views.py
...

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    sform = StudentForm(request.POST, instance=Student())

    CourseSchedule = inlineformset_factory(Student, Courses, form=CoursesForm, can_delete=False, extra=0, min_num=1)

    cforms = CourseSchedule(data=request.POST)

    if sform.is_valid() and cforms.is_valid():

        sform_obj = sform.save()
        for cform in cforms.forms:
            cform_obj = cform.save(commit=False)
            cform_obj.student = sform_obj
            cform_obj.save()

    ....
```

Comment: where is the relation in your models

Comment: first create a `m:m relationship`between two tables in `Courses` Model `students = models.ManyToManyField(Student)`

Comment: then use `inline formset` in proper way [inline](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)

Comment: It's a one to many relationship,

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.. My formset data was persisting after submission.  I had to declare an empty queryset in the basemodelformset.